# how can we export SKU with ID in magento2

Tags: product, export, sku, magento2.4.4, id

I want to export sku with magento id.

https://prnt.sc/njkYD1jkJrH0

I am trying to find how to export Product ID with a matching SKU

Comment: Below answer useful for you @kiran ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the magento2 export function does not provide a product ID so we will have to create a standalone file on the root folder. But if you are using Magento's latest version then the file will be inside the pub folder.

Please create a product-export.php file inside the pub folder and then place this code.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','sku'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->load();
                
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="product.csv"');

$user_CSV[0] = array('Product ID', 'SKU');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');

foreach ($collection as $product)
{
    $user_CSV[] = array($product->getId(), $product->getSku());
}

foreach ($user_CSV as $indexValue)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $indexValue, ',');
}

fclose($fp);
```

?>

then hit this URL in browser /product-export.php then a CSV file will be downloaded.

Hope this will help from my side.

Comment: Hi @Dotsquares,  I tried and working but showing only few sku instead of all

Comment: It should not happen as this code is properly tested and working as expected. I tried many instances even. How can I help you more apart from this?